# QEMU's QMP to listen on same socket?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Is it possible to have multiple qemu processes (machines) to listen on the same socket?

I.e. you have this identical part when starting qemu processes:

```
-qmp unix:./qmp-sock,server,nowait --monitor stdio
```

And a following question if 1st one is possible - how will you then distinguish between to which virtual machine the command was sent/how can you specify which machine will receive the command?

Sorry if this was already asked, I couldn't find anything related here or in QMP's docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only one process can be listening at any given socket location.  Think of it like a normal TCP socket.  You can't have multiple processes listening on the same IP:Port (well.. technically you can with newer linux kernels, but it doesn't do what you'd want).